# Recovering a lost/dropped session in R?

Tags: session, r, recovery

Is it possible to recover an R session if R needed to close due to an error? Is there a temp directory where sessions/data sits before its saved to a file?

What I'd really need is the history of input commands.

(running R version 2.12.1 on WinXP)

---

Based on answer to my question below, I still have the following question:

**Where is R saving .Rhistory to?**

I am not able to find this file, despite restarting a new R session and still having access to commands from a previous session. R reference page on [SAVEHISTORY](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/utils/html/savehistory.html) did not resolve this for me. It seems that R is storing this data in some temp file/folder that I don't have access to. When I run the command `tempdir()`, I get a location of the temp directory, but not a single file is being stored there, whether during an active session, or after it closes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the working directory where you were working when R crashed and look for a file named ".Rhistory" I don't know if every command will be there. But I'm sure that at least the last 50 are there.

HTH

Comment: It appears as if R does not automatically save '.Rhistory' files, as I cannot find a single one on my system, not even in the R temp directory.

Comment: @drpakin11 It seems that they are only saved when you acept to save the work space, sorry