# How to recover a lost/overwritten R file

Tags: r, rstudio, recovery

I am working on Windows 11 with RStudio and today opened an R script that I was working on during the weekend, i.e., two days prior from today. For whatever reason, when I opened the file, it was in the state of before the weekend and all my changes since then have disappeared. I have not made any backups and I am not using git.

It's absolutely unclear to me why the changes I made got lost. I am almost 100% certain that I saved the file at least once, as I do so often out of habit.

To recover overwritten files, [one post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5556978/recovering-a-lost-dropped-session-in-r) and also [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43982495/how-to-restore-lost-data-in-rstudio) recommend looking at the .RHistory file. However, that file apparently is only updated when you save the workspace on quitting, which I don't usually do. My .RHistory file has a date modified of more than two weeks ago.

I also tried looking at the files in *~/AppData/Local/RStudio/sources/session-184b7c51*. The ones I found there only contain the same version from before the weekend, however. Using a [data recovery software](https://www.cleverfiles.com/data-recovery-software.html) did not bring up any other, more recent versions.

Another thing I tried is checking the history_database files under *~/AppData/Local/RStudio*. Here I can actually find the code that I lost. Unfortunately, however, the file is over 10k lines long, compared to the ~500 lines of code that my script had. It also contains code from other scripts that I worked on in the meantime. It seems like this file records almost anything I ever wrote and/or executed in the past few days.

If all else fails, I will try to piece together my script from this file, but I hope that there is a better way. Are there any other locations where temporary data is saved that I could check or things that I could do?

Comment: (1) Consider yourself fortunate, RStudio does a lot more logging of commands/expressions than base R does. You found your code, and I believe you're going to need to pay the tax of parsing through all of the other expressions. This stinks, certainly, but at least it isn't a complete loss of code (just a loss of some time). (2) 20/20 hindsight, consider some form of code backup and/or version control. I saved my graduate thesis because of truly naive version control: every morning I committed all changes in one commit. It's bad version control but certainly better than nothing. It saved me.

Comment: If you were to adopt the "naive version control", perhaps you would benefit from doing it every evening instead of every morning ... even naive methods can be improved a little :-)

Comment: Darn, it, I guess I will bite the bullet then! It's a bit ironic because I've used git for very minor things before, and didn't set it up this time (also my graduate thesis). Thanks for the comment anyway.

Comment: @degeso any luck recovering the file? As I am currently facing the same issue with an RMD file

Comment: Unfortunately not, in the end I really did go through all the logs and reconstructed whatever I could...